# DataTable - Linq - select distinct rows based on grouping

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Here is my datatable

```
Type        Product  Action    Quantity
----------  -------  --------  --------
Fruit       Apple    Sales     1
Fruit       Apple    Sales     2
Fruit       Orange   Sales     3
Fruit       Orange   Picking   3
Vegetables  Carrot   Sales     1
Vegetables  Carrot   Sales     3
Vegetables  Carrot   Sales     3
Vegetables  Carrot   Pickings  3
```

currently I have this

```
var tableColumnGrouping =
    from table in ReportConfigurationTable.AsEnumerable()
    group table by new
    {
        column1 = table["Type"],
        column2 = table["Product"]
    }
    into groupedTable
    select new
    {
        tableColumn = groupedTable.Key,  // Each Key contains column1 and column2
        tableColumnCount = groupedTable.Count() 
    };
```

This will give me there vars of:

```
{ column1 = "Fruit", column2 = "Apple" }
{ column1 = "Fruit", column2 = "Orange" }
{ column1 = "Vegetable", column2 = "Carrot" }
```

Which is intended.  Now I want to select from the DataTable where those distinct values column grouping meets the datatable and then get the unique values for Action|Quantity.

So for the grouping of Fruit|Apple, I would return the two rows of Sales|1 Sales|2.

Or if there is a really clever way of doing this without doing a second foreach, that would be fantastic.

How do I get the unique values from the columns Action|Quantity based on the grouping on Type|Product?

Comment: it's still unclear to me on what you wants, I think you should update with detailed sample output.

Comment: it's plain as day right here so for the grouping of Fruit|Apple, i would return the two rows of Sales|1 Sales|2

Comment: I agree that the question is unclear. It seems like you should be using the `Distinct` method and with a lambda statement specifying which values you're applying distinct to but I don't want to write an answer because I'm not really sure.

Comment: so for the grouping of Fruit|Apple, i would return the two rows of Sales|1 Sales|2

Answer (score 0):

When you use Group by in Linq you can get to the underlying items as an Enumberable. All you need to do is another Select to get just the values you want

```
var rptTable = from t in ReportConfigurationTable.AsEnumerable()
                       select new {Type = t["Type"], Product = t["Product"], Action = t["Action"], Quantity = t["Quantity"]};


var tableColumnGrouping = from table in rptTable
                             group table by new { table.Type, table.Product }
                                 into groupedTable
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     tableColumn = groupedTable.Key,
                                     tableColumnCount = groupedTable.Count(),
                                     actions = groupedTable.Select(t => new {Action = t.Action, Quantity = t.Quantity})
                                 };
```

Comment: Jeremy - thanks for the attempt but i think something might be wrong with the line you provided.

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitl

Comment: .Net can't figure out what the ReportConfigurationTable contains. Try selecting into an anonymous (or a concrete type if that doesn't work) first then do the groupings etc.  Code updated